# What are the fields in /proc/pid/stat so I can parse them in C and get my own program's memory usage?

Tags: c, linux, memory

In my own Linux program, I'd like to monitor my process's own memory usage (monitor for memory leaks, etc.) and the manual way to do this is on the command-line to cat /proc/pid/stat (like `cat /proc/2421/stat` for example) and somehow decipher all the values.

The kludgy way to do this would be something like `system("cat /proc/getpid()/stat | sed bla bla")` but I'd like to properly open the file in C code and parse the correct value.

Where can I find the definition of the fields in `/proc/pid/stat` so I can parse them in C?

Answer (score 3):

The fields are defined in the Linux kernel's `fs/proc/array.c` and here is an example of how to parse them:

Here is an example of running this simple program:

```
$ ./main
My pid[7562]
Stat file [/proc/7562/stat]
Virtual Memory usage: ret[1] scanned[23] result[2342912]
```

Here is the `main()` function:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Get the current PID's virtual memory usage via /proc/pid/stat
    // for example /proc/4231/stat
    //
    // The fields are defined in the kernel source code:
    //     fs/proc/array.c
    //
    //     static int do_task_stat()
    //
    //     line 463:
    //    seq_printf(m, "%d (%s) %c", pid_nr_ns(pid, ns), tcomm, state);  // 1, 2, 3
    //    seq_put_decimal_ll(m, ' ', ppid);                               // 4
    //    seq_put_decimal_ll(m, ' ', pgid);                               // 5
    //    seq_put_decimal_ll(m, ' ', sid);                                // 6
    //    seq_put_decimal_ll(m, ' ', tty_nr);                             // 7
    //    seq_put_decimal_ll(m, ' ', tty_pgrp);                           // 8
    //    seq_put_decimal_ull(m, ' ', task->flags);                       // 9
    //    seq_put_decimal_ull(m, ' ', min_flt);                           // 10
    //    seq_put_decimal_ull(m, ' ', cmin_flt);                          // 11
    //    seq_put_decimal_ull(m, ' ', maj_flt);                           // 12
    //    seq_put_decimal_ull(m, ' ', cmaj_flt);                          // 13
    //    seq_put_decimal_ull(m, ' ', cputime_to_clock_t(utime));         // 14
    //    seq_put_decimal_ull(m, ' ', cputime_to_clock_t(stime));         // 15
    //    seq_put_decimal_ll(m, ' ', cputime_to_clock_t(cutime));         // 16
    //    seq_put_decimal_ll(m, ' ', cputime_to_clock_t(cstime));         // 17
    //    seq_put_decimal_ll(m, ' ', priority);                           // 18
    //    seq_put_decimal_ll(m, ' ', nice);                               // 19
    //    seq_put_decimal_ll(m, ' ', num_threads);                        // 20
    //    seq_put_decimal_ull(m, ' ', 0);                                 // 21
    //    seq_put_decimal_ull(m, ' ', start_time);                        // 22
    //    seq_put_decimal_ull(m, ' ', vsize);                             // 23      <----  THIS IS THE ONE WE WANT!


    pid_t mypid = getpid();
    FILE *mypidstat = NULL;

    char filename[100] = {0};

    printf("My pid[%d]\n", mypid);
    snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "/proc/%d/stat", mypid);
    printf("Stat file [%s]\n", filename);



    mypidstat = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (mypidstat == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Couldn't open [%s]\n", filename);
        return -1;
    }

    int i = 0;
    int ret = 0;
    unsigned long long val = 0;
    char strval1[100] = {0};
    char strval2[100] = {0};

    ret = fscanf(mypidstat, "%lld %s %s ", &val, strval1, strval2);
    //printf("ret[%d] scanned[%d] result[%lld] [%s] [%s]\n", ret, i, val, strval1, strval2);

    // We already scanned 3 params, so start i at the 4th
    for (i = 4; i < 24; i++) {
        ret = fscanf(mypidstat, "%lld ", &val);
        if (i == 23) {
            printf("Virtual Memory usage: ret[%d] scanned[%d] result[%lld]\n", ret, i, val);
        }

    }

    fclose(mypidstat);
    return 0;
}
```

And a simple `Makefile`

```
$ cat Makefile

CXX = gcc
COMPFLAGS = -c -Wall -g

main: main.o
        $(CXX) main.o -o main

main.o: main.c
        $(CXX) $(COMPFLAGS) main.c

clean:
        rm main main.o
```